# SQL Server Export Data failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to export a table from SQL Server 2005 using the Import/Export Wizard.  I've had no problems exporting data and have successfully exported from 5 tables before, but I am now getting this error:

> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input"
>   (114)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error
>   row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (114)" specifies failure
>   on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

This is rather frustrating as I've tried various methods to extract the data but this keeps popping up.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm trying to export to an Excel file.  I've tried to a Flat file, but it still errors.

Comment: Validate the db is intact - do a COMPLETE select of the table first. Throw the results away - just make sure you properly get the data. The run dbcc and check db integrity.

Comment: Table and database are fine.  Could it be something to do with a TEXT column being too large for an Excel column?

Comment: @Ardman - Could very well be - try wrapping the table in a view which returns empty string for the TEXT column.  Then try manipulations/conversions like LEFT(CAST(colname AS varchar(max)), 100) AS colname etc. to see if you have a datatype/length problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could very well be your TEXT column - try wrapping the table in a view which returns empty string for the TEXT column. Then try manipulations/conversions like LEFT(CAST(colname AS varchar(max)), 100) AS colname etc. to see if you have a datatype/length problem.